# Project Server 2007 Issues and Risks lists

Tags: project-server, project-server-2007

I have a EPM 2007 deployment and i'm having a hard time with the issues and risks lists... You see, if i create a new risk or issue assigned to me, when i go to the root web of the pwa, it says that I have no risks or issues assigned to me!!! Me and all users...

I thought it might be happening because of some list or site customization, so i created a new project using the default template (providade by MS, the very basic one...) and created new risks and issues, but the error remain...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up opening a ticket at MS and they fixed it... sadly they did not revealed what the problem was...